# v22.04 install on Supermicro via IPMI Virtual ISO file over the internet

Tags: iso, cloud-init, ipmi

Ok, I have a custom autoinstall cloud-init ISO that installs great on a Supermicro X11SSH-LN4F motherboard using Supermicro IPMI and its virtual Media ISO file system IF the IPMI is on the same local LAN as I am accessing it.

If I move the IPMI to a public internet IP (without any firewall beside the IPMI IP ACL), the install fails at the "waiting for cloud-init..." part and springs a language selection test UI (just like an interactive install).

My cloud-init config is dead simple:

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  identity:
    hostname: tets-jammy
    password: "$6$rounds=4096$icm4PzLbM17hy25h$X53Jlk1xPaTRDexJ4KCHaTg5lMTE/5fxJmZ9je2aQkr/STdo/C1vY.iEnkf.0.5ao385L2ihOOpxIPkLcmwKF0"
    username: admin
  package_update: false
  package_upgrade: false
  network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
      eno1:
        dhcp4: true
      eno2:
        dhcp4: true
      eno3:
        dhcp4: true
      eno4:
        dhcp4: true
  ssh:
      allow-pw: false
      authorized-keys:
        - some keys here I removed for security...
      install-server: true
```

The message I get in the test UI for the language selection is "cloud-init failed to complete after 10 minutes of waiting"... Note that I get that message when using the official Ubuntu Server ISO also...

Does anyone have any clues?

#### Edit 1

Looks like this was reported in launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/subiquity/+bug/1969919

Comment: The message I get in the test UI for the language selection is "cloud-init failed to complete after 10 minutes of waiting"...

Note that I get that message when using the official Ubuntu Server ISO also...

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers (who have better answers). Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our way to help you improve your question. All facts about your system and problem should go in the Question with [edit].  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.